# Increasing (or changing) the eccentricity of a vertex in a given graph.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, geometric-construction

I considered a graph, path $P_8$ and added two more vertices such that eccentricity of two vertices is three and rest of the vertices have eccentricity four, and $P_8$ is induced in the new graph. I got the following figure, where exactly two vertices (numbered 2 and 7) are central vertices (eccentricity two) and rest are non-central vertices i.e., diametral vertices (eccentricity four) and $P_8$ is induced in this graph.

[image]

Is there any way to get the same result for the graph path $P_9$, or other path graphs, by adding exactly two vertices. Any kind of help or suggestion will be highly useful for me. I am thankful in advance for the help.

Comment: What exactly is the result that you are looking for? Are you looking to add two vertices to $P_9$ to achieve diameter $4$ and radius $3$?

Comment: Yeah, You are right, but the condition is that only two vertices should have eccentricity 3 and rest should have eccentricity four.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to note that there is one other graph (and only one up to isomorphism) that meets your conditions on $P_8$:

[image]

Here, vertices $7$ and $9$ have eccentricity $3$ and the rest have eccentricity $4$.

I have found $76$ such graphs on $P_9$ though many of these are not unique up to isomorphism. Also, some of the graphs are subgraphs of other such graphs. A couple are listed below.

[image]

Above, vertices $1$ and $2$ have eccentricity $3$ and the rest have eccentricity $4$.

[image]

Above, vertices $7$ and $10$ have eccentricity $3$ and the rest have eccentricity $4$.

I would be happy to provide more information about the graphs if you want more. Just comment.

Comment: Amazing. That is really helpful to me. I am glad that you helped me. Really thanks a lot.

Comment: How did you manage to get such a large family of graphs?

Comment: @monalisa I used SageMath to look for graphs that had the required property. My code produced $14$ such non-isomorphic graphs on $P_9$ and $2$ on $P_8$. I would be happy to post a second answer here to classify the $14$ graphs. Just let me know.

Comment: That would be so helpful to me if you can share them. Once again thanks a lot for your efforts.

Comment: @monalisa Added another answer. Hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

These are the $15$ graphs (up to isomorphism) with this property on $P_9$.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: A million thanks for this answer. I am grateful to you. Thank you.